# Python descriptor for type checks and immutability

Tags: python, immutability, typechecking, descriptor

Read the Python Cookbook and saw descriptors, particularly the example for enforcing types when using class attributes. I am writing a few classes where that would be useful, but I would also like to enforce immutability. How to do it? Type checking descriptor adapted from the book:

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        self.name = name

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value


# by default allows None
class Typed(Descriptor):
    def __init__(self, expected_types=None, **kwargs):
        self.expected_types = expected_types

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, self.expected_types):
            raise TypeError('Expected: {}'.format(str(self.expected_types)))

        super(Typed, self).__set__(instance, value)

class T(object):
    v = Typed(int)

    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
```

Attempt #1: add a `self.is_set` attribute to Typed

```
# by default allows None
class ImmutableTyped(Descriptor):
    def __init__(self, expected_types=None, **kwargs):
        self.expected_types = expected_types
        self.is_set = False

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if self.is_set:
            raise ImmutableException(...)
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, self.expected_types):
            raise TypeError('Expected: {}'.format(str(self.expected_types)))

        self.is_set = True

        super(Typed, self).__set__(instance, value)
```

Wrong, because when doing the following, `ImmutableTyped` is 'global' in the sense that it's a singleton throughout all instances of the class. When `t2` is instantiated, `is_set` is already True from the previous object.

```
class T(object):
    v = ImmutableTyped(int)

    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

t1 = T()
t2 = T()  # fail when instantiating
```

Attempt #2: Thought instance in `__set__` refers to the class containing the attribute so tried to check if `instance.__dict__[self.name]` is still a Typed. That is also wrong.

Idea #3: Make Typed be used more similar to `@property` by accepting a '`fget`' method returning the `__dict__` of T instances. This would require the definition of a function in T similar to:

```
@Typed
def v(self):
    return self.__dict__
```

which seems wrong.

How to implement immutability AND type checking as a descriptor?

Comment: Have you tried using a single non-inheriting class that only has a `__get__` method and no set for immutability.  Also, why would you need to enforce type checking if the value is immutable? Isn't that contradicting itself?

Comment: The intent is to restrict the setting to (inside) the `__init__` method (like a Java constructor could set final variables) while also checking types. Indeed, could implement method(s) to do the type checking while maintaining immutability through `@property`. It would seem more elegant to do both in the same time though.

Answer (score 0):

Now this is my approach to the problem:

```
class ImmutableTyped:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __init__(self, *, immutable=False, types=None)
        self.immutable == immutable is True
        self.types = types if types else []

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if self.immutable is True:
            raise TypeError('read-only attribute')
        elif not any(isinstance(value, cls)
                     for cls in self.types):
            raise TypeError('invalid argument type')
        else:
           instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

Side note: `__set_name__` can be used to allow you to not specify the attribute name in initialisation. This means you can just do:

```
class Foo:
    bar = ImmutableTyped()
```

and the instance of `ImmutableTyped` will automatically have the `name` attribute `bar` since I typed for that to occur in the `__set_name__` method.

Comment: No access to Python interpreter right now, please comment if something doesn't work or does not solve your problem :)

Comment: `__set_name__` is Python 3.6+. Nevertheless, the code just doesn't work for the same reason as in my attempt #1.

Answer (score 0):

Could not succeed in making such a descriptor. Perhaps it's also unnecessarily complicated. The following method + `property` use suffices.

```
# this also allows None to go through
def check_type(data, expected_types):
    if data is not None and not isinstance(data, expected_types):
        raise TypeError('Expected: {}'.format(str(expected_types)))

    return data

class A():
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self._value = check_type(value, (str, bytes))

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value


foo = A()
print(foo.value)    # None
foo.value = 'bla'   # AttributeError
bar = A('goosfraba')
print(bar.value)    # goosfraba
bar.value = 'bla'   # AttributeError
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ImmutableTyped(object):

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __init__(self, *, types=None):

        self.types = tuple(types or [])

        self.instances = {}

        return None

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):

        is_set = self.instances.setdefault(id(instance), False)

        if is_set:
            raise AttributeError("read-only attribute '%s'" % (self.name))

        if self.types:

            if not isinstance(value, self.types):
                raise TypeError("invalid argument type '%s' for '%s'" % (type(value), self.name))

        self.instances[id(instance)] = True

        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

        return None
```

**Examples:**

```
class Something(object):

    prop1 = ImmutableTyped(types=[int])

something = Something()
something.prop1 = "1"
```

Will give:

```
TypeError: invalid argument type '<class 'str'>' for 'prop1'
```

And:

```
something = Something()
something.prop1 = 1
something.prop1 = 2
```

Will give:

```
TypeError: read-only attribute 'prop1'
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
class NameControl:
    """
    Descriptor which don't allow to change field value after initialization.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.defined = False

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not self.defined:
            self.defined = True
        elif self.defined:
            raise ValueError
```

Comment: idk if it is correct but i guees worked for me